# leaflet.js map doesn't appearing

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This is my first time working with a leaflet map in javascript, and I follow the instructions in the documentation but the map details don't appear.
This is what I get :
[image]

I search about that and found many codes that are also not working
this is my code  :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Leaflet</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
var map = L.map('map').setView([38.738853, 0.039328], 13);
bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(38.589932205137842, -0.24943472068649825), new L.LatLng(38.834130125688162, 0.250210265053367));
L.tileLayer('http://tiles.primarysolutions.org/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
minZoom: 12,
maxZoom: 15,

attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
'<a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
'Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
}).addTo(map);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where is the problem in my code and why doesn't the map appear? How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you considered updating to the latest version (v1.9.3) to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: last version of what ?

Comment: Leaflet. You're using a version from 2014 by the looks of things.

Comment: downloaded the last version - 1.9.3 and extracted the folder inside the downloads folder, just that.. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: See the [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/leaflet) and the [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/). You may also need to switch to a different tile set like https://tile.openstreetmap.org as I don't think primarysolutions.org works anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this default demo: [www.leafletjs.com/edit.html](http://www.leafletjs.com/edit.html)

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
        <style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%
}
</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    layers: [
        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            'attribution': 'Map data © <a href="https://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        })
    ],
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 0
});
```